# pylint only showing errors in VSCode

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pylint

If I have the following code:

```
print("hello")
a = 2
b =3
print "hello"
```

The only pylint message I get within VSCode or the command line is:

> Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("hello")?
>   (, line 4) pylint(syntax-error) [4,1]

If I fix the error then I get no messages from pylint within VSCode, but from a command line I get all the warnings such as bad spacing, bad const variable name, etc. and only get the above error if I call pylint with -E.

I'm running python 3.7.0 installed via miniconda.

Two questions really:
1. Is there a way to get the warnings as well as the errors at the same time
2. How do I fix VSCode to stop showing only errors

Thanks for any help.

btw, this is my settings file entry for python:

```
"[python]": {},
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
"python.linting.enabled": true,
"python.linting.lintOnSave": true,
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Seems that's the default behaviour for PyLint in VSCode. To fix it add

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--enable=F,E,W"]
```

This overrides the default (strict checks) and enables all fatal(F), error(E) & warning(W) messages. 
The vscode docs mention a lot of other ways to configure this behaviour:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_default-pylint-rules

Comment: Thanks for your help. You made me look at the 'default' settings in VS Code and I found this entry amongst the hundreds there: 'pylint use minimal checkers'.  This is checked by default. What this does when unchecked is adds: "python.linting.pylintUseMinimalCheckers": false

Setting this makes it work with showing warnings. Do you think this is a more appropriate answer, or yours?

Comment: If you define `pylintArgs` the `pylintUseMinimalCheckers` is implicitly set to `False` so it's up to you what you prefer.

Comment: Ok, I'll mark it as correct answer seeing as my comment is also here for anybody else happening to wonder. The original reason I asked is at home on my VSCode it does not do this, but the only difference is I installed Python 3.4 manually not via miniconda (python 3.7), so maybe these version or package differences has altered something?

Answer (score -3):

i simply disabled pylint for python by going to,

file>preference>python>linting

and everything is working normal and totally fine.